# shell script for loop recursive directory check

Tags: bash

I'm looking for bash script to entre into each directory and perform some action for example make zip file for each directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

function recursive_for_loop { 
    for f in *;  do 
        if [ -d $f ];  
        then  
            cd -- "$f";  
            echo "making a zip `pwd`/$f"; 
            PWD_DIR=`(pwd | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}')`
            tar cvf $PWD_DIR.tar *           

            recursive_for_loop;
            cd ..; 
        fi;  
    done;  
}

recursive_for_loop
```

Files/dirs:

```
$ tree
.
└── Inbound
    └── Lambda
        ├── app-inbound
        │   ├── a.py
        │   └── requirements.txt
        └── app-outbound
            ├── inbound-primary.py
            └── requirements.txt

4 directories, 4 files
```

When I'm trying to run the script I'm getting output as like below, not sure why I'm getting output two time (directory listing into twice) please refer the output below.

And also i need to create tar inside the each sub folders only, but its not working, can you please some one help me on this.

```
Doing something in folder /tmp/Inbound/Inbound
Doing something in folder /tmp/Inbound/Lambda/Lambda
Doing something in folder /tmp/Inbound/Lambda/app-inbound/app-inbound
Doing something in folder /tmp/Inbound/Lambda/app-outbound/app-outbound
```

Comment: Define "but its not working" — what, exactly, isn't working. What are you expecting to happen, what actually happens?  The phrase "It's not working" does not provide any useful information to help us understand the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### What I would do:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

recursive_for_loop (){
    for dir in */;  do
        (
            cd -- "$dir"
            echo "making a zip $PWD/$dir";
            recursive_for_loop
        )
    done
}

recursive_for_loop
```

##### Or using `globstar` recursion `**`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob globstar

for dir in **/;  do
    (
        cd -- "$dir"
        echo "making a zip $PWD/$dir";
    )
done
```

##### Output

```
making a zip /tmp/Inbound/Inbound/
making a zip /tmp/Inbound/Lambda/Lambda/
making a zip /tmp/Inbound/Lambda/app-inbound/app-inbound/
making a zip /tmp/Inbound/Lambda/app-outbound/app-outbound/
```

Comment: Hi @ Quenot, Thanks for the time but after echo command i need to create zip file based on the current directory something like this.

cd -- "$dir"
            echo "making a zip $PWD/$dir";
            zip $dir.zip .
            recursive_for_loop``` but unfortunately  not working it.

Comment: Yes, and do you need me to add proper code? I've done the most hard work, you just need to place whatever code you need. Do you think it's faisable?

Comment: Its not like that i have done debug as well, + shopt -s nullglob
+ recursive_for_loop
+ for dir in */
+ cd -- Inbound/
+ echo 'making a zip /tmp/Inbound/Inbound/'
making a zip /tmp/Inbound/Inbound/
+ zip Inbound/.zip .

Comment: Where do you want the zip to reside? One dir upper? In current directory?

Comment: current directory only